# Как написать правильное условие if?

Tags: php

немогу правильно организовать вывод if else

есть код вывода меню в битриксе

```
        <?if($arItem["LINK"] == '/brands/' OR $arItem["LINK"] == '/napravleniya/'):?>
                        <a class="dark-color parent "  title="<?=$arItem["TEXT"]?>">
                            <span><?=$arItem['TEXT']?></span>
                        <span class="arrow"><?=CMax::showIconSvg("triangle", SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH.'/images/svg/trianglearrow_right.svg', '', '', true, false);?></span>
                            <ul class="dropdown brandui">
                                <li class="menu_back"><a href="" class="dark-color" rel="nofollow"><?=CMax::showIconSvg('back_arrow', SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH.'/images/svg/return_mm.svg')?><?=GetMessage('MAX_T_MENU_BACK')?></a></li>
                                <li class="menu_title">
                                    <?if($arItem["LINK"] = '/catalog/'):?>
                                        <p style="margin-bottom:0"><?=$arItem['TEXT']?></p>
                                    <?else:?>
                                        <a href="<?=$arItem['LINK'];?>"><?=$arItem['TEXT']?></a>
                                    <?endif?>

                                </li>
        
                            <?if($arItem["LINK"] = '/brands/'):?>
                            
             <li>   <a href="https://site.ru/i/">пункт1</a>   </li>
  
                               <?else:?>
                      

  <li>   <a href="https://site.ru/si/">пункт2</a>   </li>
        


    <?endif?>
    
                      </ul>



                </a>
                    <?else:?>
                        <a class="dark-color<?=($bParent ? ' parent' : '')?>" href="<?=$arItem["LINK"]?>" title="<?=$arItem["TEXT"]?>">
                            <span><?=$arItem['TEXT']?></span>

                            <?if($bParent):?>
                                <span class="arrow"><?=CMax::showIconSvg("triangle", SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH.'/images/svg/trianglearrow_right.svg', '', '', true, false);?></span>
                            <?endif;?>

                </a>
                    <?endif?>
```

но почему то этот кусок кода упорно не хочет работать

```
<?if($arItem["LINK"] = '/brands/'):?>
                 <li>   <a href="https://site.ru/i/">пункт1</a>   </li>
                             <?else:?>
                    <li>   <a href="https://site.ru/si/">пункт2</a>   </li>
    
<?endif?>
```

оно только пункт1 выдает, если ставлю == то выдает пункт2, пытался еще

```
   <?if($arItem["LINK"] = '/brands/'):?>
                     <li>   <a href="https://site.ru/i/">пункт1</a>   </li>
                                 <?elseif($arItem["LINK"] = '/brands3/'):?>
                        <li>   <a href="https://site.ru/si/">пункт2</a>   </li>
        
    <?endif?>
```

но всеравно выводит так же

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте оператор сравнения '=='  вместо оператора присваивания '='

```
<?if($arItem["LINK"] == '/brands/'):?>
         "тут ваши пункты"
<?endif?>
<?if($arItem["LINK"] == '/brands-old/'):?>
         "тут другие ваши пункты"
<?endif?>
```

Comment: да я делал так, но так работало как работало дальше

Comment: что вам нужно вывести? и при каких условиях?

Comment: если <?if($arItem["LINK"] = '/brands/'):?> то выводить следующие пункты, если <?if($arItem["LINK"] = '/brands-old/'):?> то выводить другие пункты меню

Comment: отредактировал ответ